# UIStackView layout issues when changing size class in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout, size-classes, uistackview

I'm having layout issues with my horizontal `UIStackView` in a custom `UITableViewCell` when showing/hiding `arrangedSubviews` when the `horizontalSizeClass` changes.

My stack view contains a number of subviews, each of which, depending on cell configuration and size class, are either `hidden` or shown. The `UIStackView` is designed to handle arranging the shown views, but upon rotation, layout issues arise.

**Issues:**

- Sometimes, the appropriate subviews are either not shown or not hidden when they ought to be.
- Sometimes, the subviews are inappropriately laid out, not filling the stack view's width.

**Attempts:**

I've attempted a number of things to address the layout:

- Overriding `viewWillTransitionToSize:transitionCoordinator` to reload the table and/or force layout
- Overriding `viewWillTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator` to reload the table and/or force layout
- Overriding `layoutSubviews` to re-configure the stack view's `arrangedSubviews`
- Calling `[self setNeedsLayout]`, `[self layoutIfNeeded]` after configuring the cell
- Forcing layout in other places
- Changing subview layout constraint priorities to 999
- Limiting the `UILabel`s to 1 line, and setting a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`
- Adjusting the `contentCompressionResistance` and `contentHuggingPriority` on views
- Using a static value for `rowHeight` instead of `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
- Etc.

Nothing appears to fix the issues.

Furthermore, even when cells are scrolled off/on screen, prepared for reuse, and re-configured, issues either persist, go away, or new issues are introduced, despite the fact that I'm properly resetting the cell on `prepareForReuse`.

---

### Sample Project

I've created a sample project to illustrate the layout issues. At this point, I'm unsure if `UIStackView` is buggy or if I'm misusing it.

Sample Project: https://github.com/bradgmueller/StackViewTest

The sample project uses a custom `UITableViewCell` with views configured in the xib. Row objects are generated with different configurations to illustrate the dynamic layouts the cell should adopt:

- Indented / not indented
- Showing separator or not
- Showing / hiding a "like" button
- Showing / hiding a "Share" button
- Showing / hiding an Info button, where one info button exists for `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact` and another for `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular`

A text label exists with text indicating which of the views ought to be displayed, to help illustrate when views are inappropriately shown/hidden. Also, a red background view exists behind the `UIStackView` to illustrate when the stack view is failing to Fill the width.

**Screenshots:**

Initial layout - no issues
[image: Initial layout - no issues]

After rotating - issues marked with red "X"
[image: Rotation - issues arise]

---

I'd appreciate any insight, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Generally stack views are pretty good, but when they get more complicated and manage more views, they appear to be less reliable.

I found that the best way to avoid the layout issues is to do one or two things:

1. **Use multiple stack views**. Instead of bunching all of my views into the same stack view, having multiple smaller stack views seems to be more reliable, as each is managing fewer views.
2. **Remove / Re-insert views, rather than hide them**. Though stack views are supposed to treat "hidden" views as if they are removed from the hierarchy, I got much better layout results when I actually removed them from the hierarchy.

Ex:

More reliable layout results:

```
if (hideSubview == YES) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
} else {
    [stackView insertArrangedSubview:subview atIndex:0];
}
```

Not as reliable:

```
subview.hidden = hideSubview;
```